# Another Determinant Sudoku

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, sudoku, grid-deduction

sudoku-determinant have been described well here :
[The Determinant Sudoku](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52327/the-determinant-sudoku?s=13|31.9013)

I have created another one.
Number in the center is the value of the determinant
Numbers 0 to 10 are the values of the determinant

[image]

What's the solution for this sudoku?

Comment: Are you sure this has a solution that can be found purely through logical deduction? I can't find a place to start.

Comment: is that negative 2?

Comment: @Deusovi : Sorry, Not purely logical deduction. The puzzle need some computer calculation.

Comment: @Jasen : No, it is 2.

Comment: That may be why people aren't starting the puzzle. It seems like writing a computer program to solve this would be the only way to do it, and that doesn't really make a fun puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a painful coding, I think the answer is :

> [9,7,4 | 3,1,5 | 8,2,6]
>  
>  [1,2,3 | 4,6,8 | 5,7,9]
>  [5,6,8 | 2,7,9 | 1,3,4]
>  
>  -----------------------
>  [2,1,5 | 6,3,4 | 7,9,8]
>  [3,4,7 | 9,8,2 | 6,1,5]
>  [6,8,9 | 1,5,7 | 2,4,3]
>  -----------------------
>  [4,9,6 | 5,2,1 | 3,8,7]
>  [8,5,2 | 7,4,3 | 9,6,1]
>  [7,3,1 | 8,9,6 | 4,5,2]

Comment: Could you please put the answer in a more human-readable format?

Comment: wait 1 day to get the bounty prize.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the existing answer the solution is actually not unique, there are exactly two (almost trivially similar) answers

In addition to [Nurnani Tati](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/55801/150)'s answer:

> ```
> 9 7 4 | 3 1 5 | 8 2 6
> 1 2 3 | 4 6 8 | 5 7 9
> 5 6 8 | 2 7 9 | 1 3 4
> ------+-------+------
> 2 1 5 | 6 3 4 | 7 9 8
> 3 4 7 | 9 8 2 | 6 1 5
> 6 8 9 | 1 5 7 | 2 4 3
> ------+-------+------
> 4 9 6 | 5 2 1 | 3 8 7
> 8 5 2 | 7 4 3 | 9 6 1
> 7 3 1 | 8 9 6 | 4 5 2
> ```

there is also

> ```
> 9 7 4 | 3 1 5 | 8 6 2
> 1 2 3 | 4 6 8 | 5 7 9
> 5 6 8 | 2 7 9 | 1 3 4
> ------+-------+------
> 2 1 5 | 6 3 4 | 7 9 8
> 3 4 7 | 9 8 2 | 6 5 1
> 6 8 9 | 1 5 7 | 2 4 3
> ------+-------+------
> 4 9 6 | 5 2 1 | 3 8 7
> 8 5 2 | 7 4 3 | 9 1 6
> 7 3 1 | 8 9 6 | 4 2 5
> ```